# Magento2 how to create a module and displayed a template is on the front page

Tags: magento2

I created a module, but I do not know how to show a template module to the home page, I also purchased the Smartwave theme. Can anyone help me here.

[image]

smartwave is my installed theme

Comment: Have you looked at the [Devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html)?

Comment: Sorry ,I read the document but still can not do it

Comment: check for create module.
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/